# Custom-control not showing

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, amcharts

I'am having some trouble displaying a custom-control. When the page loads it's not visible, but as soon as I resize the window it appears.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<UserControl x:Class="KinectBewegingsanalyse.View.UserAnalysisChartView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:c="http://schemas.amcharts.com/stock/wpf/2009/xaml"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="600">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <c:StockChart Name="test" Visibility="Visible" PeriodSelectorVisibility="Hidden" IsEquallySpaced="False" Margin="12">
        <c:StockChart.Charts>
            <c:Chart PlotAreaBorderBrush="{StaticResource TassBlue}" PlotAreaBorderThickness="1">
                <c:Chart.DateTimeAxis>
                    <c:DateTimeAxis ValuesEnabled="True" Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="0" />
                </c:Chart.DateTimeAxis>
                <c:Chart.LeftValueAxis>
                    <c:ValueAxis ValuesFormatString="0°" Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="0" />
                </c:Chart.LeftValueAxis>
                <c:Chart.Graphs>
                    <c:Graph GraphType="Line" BulletType="RoundOutline" BulletSize="8" LegendItemType="Value" LegendValueLabelText="Gemeten waarde: " LegendValueFormatString="0°" LegendPeriodItemType="Value" />
                </c:Chart.Graphs>

                <c:Chart.Legend>
                    <c:Legend PositiveValueForeground="Black" NegativeValueForeground="Black" IsDateVisible="True" HideDateOnPeriod="False" />
                </c:Chart.Legend>
            </c:Chart>
        </c:StockChart.Charts>

        <c:StockChart.DataSets>
            <c:DataSet Brush="{StaticResource TassMagenta}" ItemsSource="{Binding PerformedAnalysis}" DateMemberPath="Date" ValueMemberPath="Angle" />
        </c:StockChart.DataSets>
    </c:StockChart>
</Grid>
```

The customc control I'm using is a StockChart from amCharts ([amCharts website](http://wpf.amcharts.com/stock)).

Thanks in advance!

Jeroen Corsius

**Update 1:**
So the Grid containing custom control has a width and height of 'NaN'. Settings an width and height for the Grid doesn't change anything.

**Update 2:**
I tried to trigger an refresh for the chart by doing one of the following:

- base.InvalidateVisual();
- base.UpdateLayout();
- grid.UpdateLayout();
- grid.InvalidateVisual();
- Chart.Focus();
- Chart.UpdateLayout();
- Chart.InvalidateVisual();
- Chart.Refresh();

All without any result.

**Update 3:**
When performing `Chart.Refresh();` on a Button Click-event, the Chart shows up.

Comment: Can you show an example of the Window where you're using it?

Comment: I'm using MVVM so the above code is loaded into an ItemsControl in my MainWindow.xaml:
`<ContentControl Margin="0, 100, 0, 0" Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />`

Comment: A where is your datatemplate?

Comment: It's defined in an external file like this:
    `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:UserAnalysisChartViewModel}">
        <v:UserAnalysisChartView />
    </DataTemplate>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following event on your chart: `Loaded="Chart_Loaded"`, add the following rule in the event handler: `Chart.Refresh();`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Use [snoop](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=wpf%20snoop&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsnoopwpf.codeplex.com%2F&ei=Z6l9T8XXLKHU0QXOjpXCDQ&usg=AFQjCNGOZqCZyA9ShSXslnP5ypdWZM1UnA) to inspect the visual tree and see where the tree is broken.

Comment: I have used Silverlight spy, I like your answer. +1

Comment: I can't find any problems in the visual tree. As soon as I click the custom-control in the TreeView (from Snoop) it also appears in my application.

Comment: That sounds like a licensing issue. Is the control you use commercial? - If so did you include the licx file in the UI project?

Comment: No the control is under linkware license. That means that it´s allowed to use it as long is you leave the link visible. See [link](http://wpf.amcharts.com/licenses/free/stock/).

Comment: Then check the width and height in snoop, perhaps some control binding overrides it.

Comment: As soon as I click the the control in the Tree (inside Snoop) the control becomes visible. So I don't see any possible way to check the width/height and prevent it from showing. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Try clicking only on element above it and those above that within visual tree.

Comment: The element directly above it is a Grid, it's width and height are both 'NaN'. Setting these to 'Auto' or actual values it's still not showing.

Comment: @DannyVarod: Great answer, another in my case I had no controls in the visual tree which made me realise I'd forgotten to apply my custom template.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have minwidth set to zero by either the custom control or the thing containing it. Exactly the same happened to me in Silverlight when studio or blend added minwidth=0 as a default.

Comment: I don't have any minWidth's set on that page, but thanks for the tip.